# Hide Grub not working?

Tags: grub2, linux-headers

I have tried every solution I could find on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) to hide the grub menu, but it always shows up.

The following is my configuration (`/etc/default/grub`):

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE="/boot/grub/background.png"
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="white/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="white/black"

GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/kali/theme.txt"
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not testing these suggestions because I do not want to set a default. Nor do I know how to recover if something were to go awry, so, standard disclaimer...

"Back everything up and use at your own risk"

That being said, the below suggestions seem harmless to the system. Just a thought, you MAY be able to recover using the 'edit' feature in the GRUB menu.

Good luck!

### References are listed below the suggestions.

> I would try changing: GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
> to: GRUB_DEFAULT=0

This is assuming that the default you want to use is the first GRUB menu item (0=first, 1=second, etc). [And for font's sake: 0=zero]

> Otherwise, you can quote the actual menu item title that you choose in the GRUB menu:  
> GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu (lowlatency)"

> Or go deeper by finding the title. I found mine in "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" on the first "menuentry" line. It is after "$menuentry_id_option".... it is: 'gnulinux-simple-ea05c38e-393e-41ee-8cfe-f17f93b818af'
> GRUB_DEFAULT='gnulinux-simple-ea05c38e-393e-41ee-8cfe-f17f93b818af'

You probably only want to stick to the "menuentry" lines and NOT the "submenu" or 'submenu + menuentry' lines.

> And maybe you can also try in a terminal: "grub-set-default 0"

And that's all I have for now. Peace........

_____Below is the terminal output from "grub-set-default --help"

Usage: grub-set-default [OPTION] MENU_ENTRY
Set the default boot menu entry for GRUB.
This requires setting GRUB_DEFAULT=saved in /etc/default/grub.

-h, --help              print this message and exit
-V, --version           print the version information and exit
--boot-directory=DIR    expect GRUB images under the directory DIR/grub
instead of the /boot/grub directory

MENU_ENTRY is a number, a menu item title or a menu item identifier.

Report bugs to bug-grub@gnu.org.
__ output end_________________________________________

_____Excerpt from "info grub"

Next: fallback,  Prev: debug,  Up: Special environment variables

### 15.1.10 default

If this variable is set, it identifies a menu entry that should be
selected by default, possibly after a timeout (*note timeout::).  The
entry may be identified by number (starting from 0 at each level of the
hierarchy), by title, or by id.

For example, if you have:

menuentry 'Example GNU/Linux distribution' --class gnu-linux --id example-gnu-linux {
...
}

then you can make this the default using:

```
 default=example-gnu-linux
```

If the entry is in a submenu, then it must be identified using the
number, title, or id of each of the submenus starting from the top
level, followed by the number, title, or id of the menu entry itself,
with each element separated by '>'.  For example, take the following
menu structure:

```
 GNU/Hurd --id gnu-hurd
   Standard Boot --id=gnu-hurd-std
   Rescue shell --id=gnu-hurd-rescue
 Other platforms --id=other
   Minix --id=minix
     Version 3.4.0 --id=minix-3.4.0
     Version 3.3.0 --id=minix-3.3.0
   GRUB Invaders --id=grub-invaders
```

The more recent release of Minix would then be identified as 'Other
platforms>Minix>Version 3.4.0', or as '1>0>0', or as
'other>minix>minix-3.4.0'.

This variable is often set by 'GRUB_DEFAULT' (*note Simple
configuration::), 'grub-set-default', or 'grub-reboot'.

_____ output end________________________________